USB debugging not showing in developer settings
after tapping the Build number seven times, no message came up, but I was able to go to developer settings. The problem is that there is no USB debugging option there at all...what's wrong? the only debug I see is "enable node tree debugging" and enable debug log overlay". I have a samsung A22 android version 13. thanks!
trying to show android screen on the computer

seems like it's restricted by the mobile provider/company. where did you get the device from? Is it brand new? check if there is an MDM app installed on it.
